# Should I install GCC 64 bit on a new server?

Tags: 64-bit, configuration, 32bit-64bit, gcc

I am going to rebuild my server and I am wondering whether I should install GCC 32 or 64 bit. I develop in Python and I use some libraries that would benefit from a 64 bit GCC installation but I am not sure if I am going to run into problems with other programs / libraries. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My rule of thumb is:

When your machine has less than 4 gigabytes of RAM, none of your processes needs more than 2 gigabytes of memory and you do not need any of the new instructions of the x86_64 instruction set, go with a 32 bit (x86) system.

Otherwise choose 64 bit (x86_64).

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb is :

Go for 64-bit. It doesn't hurt. Every processor alive today supports it (except the Intel Atom). 32-bit will diseappear one day, 64-bit still has a long life ahead of it.

If it's a server app, go 64-bit and maintain some sort of retrocompatibility.